# How can I 'hg clone' from another machine?

Tags: mercurial

I have 2 Ubuntu laptops in the same WiFi network. I would like to 'hg clone' from 1 laptop to another.

In my source laptop, 
I have a 'hg' repository in ~/work/myserver

and my source laptop ip address  inet addr:192.168.1.2.

So what should i do on my dest laptop so that I can clone my hg repository?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like so:

```
hg clone ssh://your-user@192.168.1.2//home/my-user/work/myserver/
```

Note: If you're running a firewall on 192.168.1.2, you'll need to open port 22 for SSH. I believe Ubuntu uses ufw by default.

Note 2: Replace your-user with the user you use to login when you're sitting at 192.168.1.2

Comment: The path is relative to the user's home directory by default, if you want to use an absolute url as in your example you need an extra / before the path.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, for some reason Git doesn't require that.

Answer (score 7):

My choice between two Linux computers would also be going through ssh, as [suggested by Zack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756555/how-can-i-hg-clone-from-another-machine/2756570#2756570).

One alternative that also works on Windows machines is to use the integrated web server to expose your repository, then clone from there.

First you run `hg serve` that will by default get you a web server on port 8000, then you just  `hg clone http://machine1:8000`, with the added benefit that you get a nice graphical view of your history. ([more information here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/hgserve))